# Scaling properly to zero when using ggplot's scale_size for log-type distributed data in Windows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data ranging in value from 1 to around 10,000, to be mapped to line size (width).  The problem is ggplot seems to assign a non-zero minimum line width even when the range minimum is specified as zero.  For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), y=c(0,10,0,10,0,10,0,10,0,10), 
               cat=rep(letters[1:5],each=2), size=c(1,1,10,10,100,100,1000,1000,10000,10000))
print(d)
   x  y cat  size
1  1  0   a     1
2  1 10   a     1
3  2  0   b    10
4  2 10   b    10
5  3  0   c   100
6  3 10   c   100
7  4  0   d  1000
8  4 10   d  1000
9  5  0   e 10000
10 5 10   e 10000
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, size=size, group=cat)) + geom_line() + scale_size_continuous(range = c(0, 5))
```

[image]

For larger datasets this means the most insignificant data rows end up dominating the plot.  Of course I could filter out smallest data points, but would prefer to avoid exceptional measures.  Can ggplot scale linearly to size, including to zero width if the data value is sufficiently small.  Am I missing a parameter?  I'd also prefer a linear scale as opposed to manual log method..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With your sample data and code I don't see the lines at x=1,2,3 (ggplot2 version 1.0.0, Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit))

Comment: Ah so it's a Windows issue.  But I still get the same result using ggsave, so it's not just in the GUI..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I export with `ggsave("test.svg", p)` (and then export a PNG from Inkscape) I get the same result on my win7 machine as plotting on our ubuntu server:

[image: resulting image]

Comment: Thanks. This is the closest to a solution we're going to get

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to also map `alpha` to `size`.  Since `alpha` controls the translucency, the very thin lines in your resulting plot are also almost completely transparent:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, size=size, group=cat, alpha=size)) + 
  geom_line() + scale_size_continuous(range = c(0, 5))
```

[image]

Comment: Useful workaround thanks Andrie if there's not a more formal solution